# Concat all columns to one string in a mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I want to concat every column within a table to one string separated with a separator. In PySpark this would look like this:

```py
concat_ws("#?", *columns)
```

What would be the equivalent in data flow expression language?

```
concatWS('#?', columns())
```

won't work. I get the following error:

> "Error: Function 'concatWS' argument 3 should be StringType but was
> BinaryType"

Spark obviously implicitly converts every column to a string

Even tried this, but does not work either:

```
concatWS('#?', toString(byNames(columnNames())))
```

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: one of your column is of type binary, so concat take input of type string you need to decode the binary and concat. add the screenshot of the input columns.

Comment: Right now, in PySpark I use this function on more than 1000 Datasets with different datatypes without any issue. I just want an general approach which is not dependent on the schema of the source dataset.

Comment: I have added the expression which convert BinaryType to StringType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is correct and working fine.
`concatWS('#?', columns())`

If you still not getting expected results you can use the below alternate expressions.

`concatWS('#?', toString(columns()))`

Or

`rtrim(toString(reduce(map(array(columns()),toString(#item)+'#?'),'', #acc +  toString(#item), #result)),'#?')`

Below is the columns i am having.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but I get the following error on the first dataset I tried: Error:
cannot resolve 'arraynull([...])' due to data type mismatch: input to function arraynull should all be the same type, but it's [string, binary, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, decimal(16,2), decimal(16,2), decimal(16,2), decimal(5,1), string, decimal(28,6), decimal(11,0), decimal(11,0), string, decimal(15,0), string, string, ...];

Comment: Try this `concatWS('#?', toString(columns()))`

Comment: Thats the trick! Thank you!

Comment: BTW: is there an explaination somewhere, why this works? The documentation states toSting as follows: ```toString(<value> : any, [<number format/date format> : string], [<date locale> : string]) => string```but in this working solution it more looks like it's returning a list of strings??

Comment: Whatever the columns come from `columns()` is converted to string, before it was directly concatenated.